# How to deploy multiple firebase hostng projects from travis at the same time (no staging or production just other websites)

Tags: firebase, travis-ci, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I want to deploy from Travis multiple firebase hosting projects at the same time that is possible??, if yes I gonna be happy :)

Because I have 10 projects right now that all are the same code I think is easier for me to deploy from 1 git repo to all my websites  at the same time, now I do that 1 in the time and  is take me 4-5 hours to do that

### my .travis.yml

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "7"

branches:
  only:
    - master

before_script:
  - npm install -g firebase-tools
  - npm install -g @angular/cli

script:
  - ng build --prod

after_success:

  - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN_1 <-- this is for https://project1.firebaseapp.com
  - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN_2 <-- this is for https://project2.firebaseapp.com
  - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN_3 <-- this is for https://project3.firebaseapp.com
  - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN_4 <-- this is for https://project4.firebaseapp.com
  - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN_5 <-- this is for https://project5.firebaseapp.com
  - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN_6 <-- this is for https://project6.firebaseapp.com

notifications:
  email:
    on_failure: change
    on_success: change
```

Is that possible?

Comment: frank can you help me is that possible??

Answer (score 5):

Yes, absolutely. Just declare the projects in your .firebaserc file

`{
  "projects": {
     "project1": "firebase-project-id-1",
      "project1": "firebase-project-id-1",
      ... 
      "project10": "firebase-project-id-10"
   }
}`

And then you just switch active project between each `firebase deploy`

`- firebase use project1 --token $FIREBASE_DEPLOY_KEY1
- firebase deploy --non-interactive --token $FIREBASE_DEPLOY_KEY1
... 
- firebase use project10 --token $FIREBASE_DEPLOY_KEY10
- firebase deploy --non-interactive --token $FIREBASE_DEPLOY_KEY10`

Comment: OMG OMG I am so happy I want to Thank you, Brother, if you need help in vacations in Greece that summer I am here

Comment: Dennis how I can take $FIREBASE_DEPLOY_KEY10 I type *firebase login:ci * and is give me a token but I think for projet_10 I get the same token like all others

Comment: I try but is not working I see something to deploy on my project 2 but is not take the changes

Comment: Have a look at how I deploy my website with Travis CI to Firebase. I've got a staging and production project. You can use the same logic for two or ten projects: https://github.com/kumpul/kumpul-website-jekyll/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: Thanx denis I don't want to update the alias of the same project, but defriend projects with defriend domain name, all have the same code the only defriend is the domain name

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Dennis' great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44088195). After configuring the [aliases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#project_aliases), you can simplify even a little bit more.

Instead of switching the 'active' project with `firebase use`, you can explicitly set the project for the current command, i.e. when deploying you can set the corresponding project using the `-P` or `--project` flag

```
firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN_1 -P project1
```

or

```
firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN_1 --project project1
```

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#use_aliases):

> You can override what's being used as the currently active project by passing the `--project` flag with any CLI command. [...] If you want to run a single command against the Firebase project that you've assigned the prod alias, then you can run, for example, `firebase deploy --project=prod`.

... or in the help section of the CLI:

```
$ firebase --help | grep '\--project'
  -P, --project <alias_or_project_id>    the Firebase project to use for this command
```

One more addition: I assume that you have access to all the projects with the same user. This is not explicitly specified in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#cli-ci-systems), but the tokens are associated with your user, not the project. That means you should be able to use the same token to successfully deploy to every environment.

So, your build script could be reduced to

```yaml
after_success:

  - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN -P project1 
  - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN -P project2
  - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN -P project3
  - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN -P project4
  - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN -P project5
  - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN -P project6
```